# Cannot access resource icons when running with osmdroid-android-3.0.7

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am trying to start a simple map activity that displays a map an a couple of markers using osmdroid-android-3.0.7 library. The code worked under an older version (1.10). I am getting the following error:
02-03 15:14:30.574: E/AndroidRuntime(10277): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource not found: marker_default.png

When I unzipped the jar file I can see a list of icons in the top level directory and one of them is indeed marker_default.png. This is the snippet of the code:

```
public class MapDisplay extends Activity 
{
    private MapView mapView;
    private ResourceProxy resProxy;
    private ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> locationOverlay;

    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedState);

        resProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());

        final RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this); 

        mapView = new MapView(this, 256);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(6);
             mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(51500000, 5400000));
                  rl.addView(mapView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams 
                      (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        final ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        OverlayItem o1 = new OverlayItem("Location 1", "Comment", 
                       new GeoPoint(51500000, 5400000));
                  o1.setMarker(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icall));
        items.add(o1);
        OverlayItem o2 = new OverlayItem("Location 2", "Comment", 
                       new GeoPoint(52500000, 5500000));
                  o2.setMarker(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icall));
        items.add(o2);
                  this.locationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
                    new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, 
                                      final OverlayItem item) 
                        {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                                MapDisplay.this,
                                                "Item '" + item.mTitle + "' (index=" + index
                                                                + ") got single tapped up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return true; // We 'handled' this event.
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, 
                          final OverlayItem item) 
                        {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                                MapDisplay.this,
                                                "Item '" + item.mTitle + "' (index=" + index
                                                                + ") got long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return false;
                        }
                }, resProxy);
           this.mapView.getOverlays().add(this.locationOverlay);
           mapView.invalidate();
                this.setContentView(rl);
    }
}
```

When I tried to use a simple overlay and therefore did not set any icons for the marker then I got the same error except it referred to person.png (that icon is also in the unzipped jar file). 
I have added the jar file via project properties and can access the api just fine.

Why can't I access the icons?

BTW, I tried to copy the icons into my project but I got the same error.

Thanks, Ania

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - in the latest jar (3.0.8) the issue is fixed.

Comment: Where did you get 3.0.8 from?  A local build saying 3.0.8 is not 3.0.8

Comment: This jar works ok - [link](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/osmdroid/osmdroid-android/3.0.8-SNAPSHOT/osmdroid-android-3.0.8-20120208.220818-1.jar)

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=305) in the bug tracker which I think has a solution for this.  Have not had the issue myself I provide my own bitmap.  I do remember all the proxy stuff being confusing and troublesome.

Comment: I reported the issue you mentioned, which is exactly the same as this question, so I would say this is definitely a bug in osmdroid :( The workaround is either to patch the osmdroid as explained in the issue or to provide your own icons (I believe by implementing the proxy stuff).

Comment: Thanks. For now I will use an earlier version. Hopefully the bugs will be fixed soon.