# Impossible to instantiate an OsmDroid MapView

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-mapview, osmdroid

I'm trying to use OSMdroid for a project, and i'm utterly unable to make the simplest code work.
Well, a few days ago i was able to display maps and so on, and now i can't even instantiate a MapView.
I reduced the code to its sipmlest form.
I work with eclipse. I downloaded osmdroid-android-3.0.5.jar and slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar, and i included them in the project by adding lines to the classpath file

```
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/osmdroid-android-3.0.5.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar"/>
```

Or by right clicking on them then Build Path-> Add to build path (both gave the same result, anyway)

Then i typed this code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestMapActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mv=new MapView(this,256);

    }
}
```

And i get a bug when running it on the emulator:

```
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:           org.osmdroid.views.MapView
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at     testmap.sagem.TestMapActivity.onCreate(TestMapActivity.java:17)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-17 09:10:31.181: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When i comment out the "MapView mv=new MapView(this,256);" it works, so i don't understand why the mapview can't be instantiated.

Any idea on this?

Thank you for your attention.

EDIT:
The AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="testmap.sagem"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

The main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Folder name "lib" to "libs" and put all jar files in that folder and Charge path of jar 
files to "libs" folder. I am not sure but I think it will work.

Comment: Ooooh. God bless you. I didn't think that would work, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the 3.0.7 and clean the project.
Let me know.
http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/downloads/list

Comment: Well i tried it, but i had the same bug. I also tried with the slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar instead of 1.5.8, but again, same bug

Comment: By checking this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135284/cannot-access-resource-icons-when-running-with-osmdroid-android-3-0-7

I could suggest to use this: [link to jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/osmdroid/osmdroid-android/3.0.8-SNAPSHOT/osmdroid-android-3.0.8-20120208.220818-1.jar)

Comment: can you also add the xml file?

Comment: @ N3sh : I had hope that time but eventually same behavior.

Comment: yeah, the new SDK requires you to put all the libraries into libs. Why didnt I think about it^^. Glad you fixed it