# How To Include OsmDroid in Eclipse Project

Tags: android, eclipse, osmdroid

I try to include osmdroid as a library in my eclipse android project.

When I hit run it gets:

```
RUN TIME Exception no Resource found.
```

How should I include osmdroid if I want to make changes to the library?

Comment: Check links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135284/cannot-access-resource-icons-when-running-with-osmdroid-android-3-0-7 & http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=305

Comment: Try to download latest jar for osmdroid